# Get index of a number from list

Tags: python, list

```
[('3604', 0.7113370895385742),
 ('63', 0.6787939071655273),
 ('6566', 0.6688929796218872),
 ('6406', 0.6664271354675293),
 ('15', 0.6614164113998413)]
```

I want to get index of the first instance instead that is:

```
[(log[3604], 0.7113370895385742),
 (log[63], 0.6787939071655273),
 (log[6566], 0.6688929796218872),
 (log[6406], 0.6664271354675293),
 (log[15], 0.6614164113998413)]
```

So far I am doing this:

```
new_sentence = "My Order".split(" ")  
sen2vec.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[sen2vec.infer_vector(new_sentence)],topn=5)
```

to get the list. Any suggestions will help!

Comment: Doesn't make sense. the index of what? What are the 2 last lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
l = [('3604', 0.7113370895385742),
 ('63', 0.6787939071655273),
 ('6566', 0.6688929796218872),
 ('6406', 0.6664271354675293),
 ('15', 0.6614164113998413)]
print([(log[int(i)], n) for i, n in l])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have some object called log that you wish to access by indexing.

If this is the case, wouldn't this be a way to do this?

```
a =[('3604', 0.7113370895385742),
  ('63', 0.6787939071655273),
  ('6566', 0.6688929796218872),
  ('6406', 0.6664271354675293),
  ('15', 0.6614164113998413)]

log = range(10000)

b = [(log[int(x[0])], x[1]) for x in a]
print b
```